# revoking removeFromSuperview?

Tags: iphone

[((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView) removeFromSuperview];

it removes `cell.backgroundView` from the `UITableviewCell`, but how can I bring it back again ..?
(add again that view?)

Answer (score 2):

```
[cell addSubview:myBackgroundView]
```

Where the `myBackgroundView` is a UIImageView. If you keep `myBackgroundView` as an instance variable, you could simply add it again. If you do not, you need to reinitialize the backgroundView;

```
UIImageView *myBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image"]] autorelease];
```

Something like that.

Comment: After removerFromSuperview, addSubview doesn't work. We need to re-initiate the UIView. Copy paste the UIView element initiation.  ex.   backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; and so on

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep a reference to the superview, and use `addSubview`:

```
UIView *imageView = (UIView *)cell.backgroundView;
UIView *imageSuperview = imageView.superView; // I assume it's cell, but just in case

// Remove imageView
[imageView removeFromSuperview];

// Add it again
[imageSuperview addSubview:imageView];
```

If you store the imageView in fields and such, please ensure that you retain your references properly.